# Javascript json customization issue

Tags: javascript

```
[
  {
    "S1": [
      10.600004,
      12.7
    ],
    "S2": [],
    "S3": [
      18.400034
    ],
    "S4": [
      11.700008
    ],
    "S5": [
      4.499998
    ]
  },
  {
    "S1": [
      6.89999
    ],
    "S2": [
      12,
      12.4
    ],
    "S3": [
      73.699448
    ],
    "S4": []
  }
]
```

Hi here i am trying to manipulate one json file to below format.
I am not able to think how to do that ?

The way i am thinking is not efficient thats why i need hep on this ?

Is there any easy way to do this.

Please have a look

```
[
  {
    "zone": [
      {
        "timeInfo": [
          10.600004,
          12.7
        ]
      },
      {
        "timeInfo": []
      },
      {
        "timeInfo": [
          18.400034
        ]
      },
      {
        "timeInfo": [
          11.700008
        ]
      },
      {
        "timeInfo": [
          4.499998
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "zone": [
      {
        "timeInfo": [
          6.89999
        ]
      },
      {
        "timeInfo": [
          12,
          12.4
        ]
      },
      {
        "timeInfo": [
          73.699448
        ]
      },
      {
        "timeInfo": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

THis this the output i am expecting for.

Please have a look
Is there any way to achive it?

Comment: please add your code.

Comment: It was more code i simplified to this. I have not started after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should work,

```
const inData = [
  {
    "S1": [
      10.600004,
      12.7
    ],
    "S2": [],
    "S3": [
      18.400034
    ],
    "S4": [
      11.700008
    ],
    "S5": [
      4.499998
    ]
  },
  {
    "S1": [
      6.89999
    ],
    "S2": [
      12,
      12.4
    ],
    "S3": [
      73.699448
    ],
    "S4": []
  }
];
const outData = [];
let timeZone;
for (const obj of inData) {
  timeZone = { zone: [] };
  for (const arr of Object.values(obj)) {
    timeZone.zone.push({ timeInfo: arr});
  }
  outData.push(timeZone);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(outData));
```

Comment: Glad it help you!.